# Is a formula that isoalates a type necessarily inside the type?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Suppose that $p(x)$ is a complete n-type and for every $\psi(x)\in p(x)$ we have that

$$ T\vDash\phi(x)\rightarrow\psi(x) $$.

Is it it necessarily the case that $\phi(x)\in p(x)$ (assuming $\phi$ is not $\bot$)?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? What have you tried?

Comment: @MarkKamsma It seems consistent to me that a structure satisfies the conditional, $\psi(x)$, and $\neg\phi(x)$. But I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varphi(x)\notin p(x)$, then since $p(x)$ is complete, $\lnot \varphi(x)\in p(x)$. Now by our hypothesis, $T\models \varphi(x)\rightarrow \lnot \varphi(x)$, which implies $T\models \lnot \varphi(x)$. So $\varphi(x)$ is equivalent to $\bot$, modulo $T$.

Note that if $p(x)$ is only a partial type, it is quite possible to have a consistent formula which entails every formula in $p(x)$ (I wouldn't say "isolates", when $p$ is not complete), but which is not itself entailed by $p(x)$.

Comment: Wow, I should've seen that. Thank you!